# How was Azazel captured?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Trask is always trying to capture the mutants alive. It would seem that Azazel was also captured alive, to get his bone and tissue cells.

But how was Azazel killed and captured? Can't he teleport out to anywhere at any time?

Comment: wasnt azazel killed?

Comment: I said... he was killed  and captured... mystique sees his autopsy

Comment: seeing his autopsy doesnt lead me to believe he was captured, just killed. which is far easier to do to azazel, my point was your title is slightly misleading because we never KNOW if he was captured first and then killed. or if a bullet got him when he wasnt looking and killed him, we also dont know if azazel and magneto captured together, so its potentially 2 separate incidents/questions

Comment: I see your point... but from what I understood, it seems that they needed live samples for their subjects...and based on all other incidents...it was more likely that he was captured...but nothing for sure. Its just ambiguous and I am trying to find out

Comment: Teleporters need to be conscious to teleport. Hit him with a tranq while he's asleep, or generally catch him by surprise. Additionally, teleporting typically takes a toll on the 'porter. This is not the case with Azazel in the comics, but we don't know if movie-Azazel had the same proficiency as his comics counterpart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Azazel wasn’t captured, he was killed.**

There’s a newspaper article, [*The Bent Bullet Report*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zJKwxWZbz-gcccMzFx6KsxLRbCc2ETn/view), which was part of the promotional material for *Days of Future Past*. It’s an explanation of President Kennedy’s assassination, and the alleged role of mutants (namely Magneto) in his death. The full text includes a few mentions of Azazel.

> Indeed, two members of Lehnsherr’s own Brotherhood of Mutants, an organization the FBI classified as “a pro-mutant terrorist group,” were killed [in 1963]. **The mutants code-named Azazel and Tempest were slain by Project: WideAwake operatives in July.**

There’s an explanation of Project: WideAwake elsewhere in the article:

> Project: WideAwake was a covert CIA task force President Kennedy created after the Cuban Missile Crisis to investigate other X-Gene cases. While its mission was identification and research, it did have paramilitary autonomy. **Records state Azazel and Tempest ambushed Project: WideAwake operatives, and died in the firefight that followed.**

I’m sure Trask (or anybody) would have preferred Azazel alive for their studies, but it’s hard to be picky about these things. A stray bullet at the wrong time, and he’s dead, teleport or no teleport.

Remember that Azazel would probably be facing soldiers who had some idea of mutant capabilities – possibly even with specific intelligence about Azazel’s powers. Teleportation is a useful skill, but it doesn’t make you indestructible. If he was complacent against a group of operatives trained to handle a teleport, it’s very possible he’d be outmanoeuvred.

---

WideAwake is not a new concept; it’s part of the [Earth-616 universe in the comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Wideawake_(Earth-616)). This also isn’t the first time it’s been seen on screen; it’s a folder on Stryker’s computer in *X2*:

[image]

Comment: It just seems very silly of the mutants, Magneto getting captured and Azazel killed...considering X-men First class...where the humans were in awe of the mutant powers towards the end of the movie...

Comment: Also, it should be noted that the CIA had encountered Azazel once already, when he came with Sebastian Shaw and the rest of the Hellfire Club and they attack a CIA base in X-Men: First Class